# IIS Web.config file redirect rules stops working after adding more than 3 rules

Tags: html, web, iis, web.config-transform

Hoping someone can help, I have a redesigned a site recently and need to redirect some URL's. I find it easier doing this in the Web.config file in IIS and have the current rules setup. Any more rules after this will break all the redirects and I get errors that the site is being redirected to many times. I have set it so that the stopPorcessing is true so it shouldn't try and redirect more than it is asked to?

```
<rule name="New About us Redirect" stopProcessing="true"><match url="^(about-us.*)" /><action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite.co.uk/about.html" /></rule>

<rule name="New Rule meet-the-team" stopProcessing="TRUE"> <match url= "^(meet-the-team.*)"/> <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite.co.uk.co.uk/team.html" /> </rule>

<rule name="New Rule it-solutions" stopProcessing="TRUE"> <match url= "^(solutions.*)"/> <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite.co.uk/services.html" /> </rule>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding a rule via IIS Manager to see if it generates anything different from your manual additions? Looking at [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module), it appears that the `http://www.mysite.co.uk/` should not be there - and also, that would interfere with HSTS when you implement that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules You can track down what's happening under the hood.

Comment: The second rule redirects request to www.mysite.co.uk.co.uk, but first one and third one redirect to www.mysite.co.uk. Make sure the host name is correctly. Change the action type to rewrite and use failed request tracing to troubleshoot what caused the issue.

Comment: I found the issue, I was using the wildcard at the end of the pattern match which when redirecting to the new page was trying to redirect again. I have taken the wildcard out and replaced with a trailing slash which the original site was using on the URL's.